# Scoped storage support ContentResolver.insert returning null on some devices

Tags: android, database, android-contentresolver, mediastore, scoped-storage

I have an Android application which involves downloading and saving Media files (Images, Videos, Audio, Documents). Earlier I was creating a directory in File system and download and save these files in that directory. However, due to restrictions in storage access and the introduction of Scoped Storage, for android 11, we have resorted to using MediaStore APIs. The problem I am facing is while using ContentResolver.insert() API, I am getting null uri in some devices (most of which are Samsung, but also happening in OnePlus, Redmi, Vivo, POCO). Is there a way around this? I need this uri to access the DATA column to get complete file path.

My current code for saving Image is as follows:

```
ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

Uri collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);

contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "image.png");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyPicturesDirectory");
Uri result = resolver.insert(collection, contentValues);
```

For other media types, I have similar separate concrete implementations.

Comment: `The APIs getCollectionToUse, getMediaStoreDisplayNameKey, getMediaStoreMimeTypeKey` Dont use your own apis as we have no idea what they do. Just post code that we can copy and paste to try out.

Comment: Further tell where you think a file would land on file system using insert() without RELATIVE_PATH column.

Comment: I need this uri to access the data column to save my file.` Dont understand what you do with data column.

Comment: @blackapps updated the code for images. As this issue is happening only on some devices with Android 11, I am not sure if you can replicate it. As per documentation for [RELATIVE_PATH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#RELATIVE_PATH), default location is provided when no value is given. I am expecting an absolute path via the DATA column after this insert has happened. As per my understanding, you cannot assign value to DATA column for Android 11 but can read the values from it. But a uri is required for quering DATA column.

Comment: But what is the default location? And use RELATIVE_PATH to see if that is the problem.

Comment: I do not understand for what you need the DATA column if you have a nice uri.

Comment: `mMimeType` Again: we cannot copy/paste as what would be the value? Also for display name as certain extensions can be refused.

Comment: On Android 11 use IS_PENDING twice.

Comment: @blackapps: DATA column will contain the complete file path. This can be used with Java File APIs. I am using this DATA column value with Java File APIs, hence uris are not useful for me. The problem I am facing is not with Android APIs, but with behavior of these APIs on some devices as the code is working fine on pixel devices with Stock android. I have updated the code for your reference, please do try and let me know if you find any issue with this.

Comment: @blackapps: I dont think there is a need to use IS_PENDING twice as I can directly expose the filepath after insertion as my file will be copied and my IO operation to copy file to destination will happen synchronously in a single background thread.

Comment: If insert() returns null you can do nothing further. Now try with IS_PENDING and RELATIVE_PATH. You did not tell where files would land if you dont use relative path...  it was asked you ... try with... which Android version on devices with cursor==null... why does this take so much time..

Comment: @Roadblock did you resolve the issue? I'm facing same issue

Comment: @TranManh: No. Have raised the issue on issue tracker http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185534814